# What's the status of Raspberry Pi support?

Tags: arm

Will 12.10's arm edition support raspberry pi?  I just bought one and would prefer running Ubuntu over Fedora.

Comment: I guess it is too early to post a solution for Ubuntu 12.10

Comment: Raise a Lauchpad bug.

Answer (score 4):

I think you will have more luck with [Raspbian](http://www.raspbian.org/) distribution. It is debian based and geared specifically for the Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 4):

Ubuntu dropped support for that style of ARM architecture a few years ago (9.10).

While this is great for supporting newer hardware it means that Ubuntu does not run on hardware like the Raspberry Pi and likely never will:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/848154