# Will 12.10's arm edition support raspberry pi?

Tags: grub2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Raspberry Pi support for 12.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/163694/raspberry-pi-support-for-12-10)

I just bought one and would prefer running Ubuntu over Fedora.

(Please don't close this question again). I am also looking for an answer to this. There is nothing wrong with the question format. Please don't be over-eager admins.